# C or C++ BigInt library on Microsoft Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, biginteger

What arbitrary-precision integers (and or rationals) library are there for compilers running on Microsoft Windows, and which would you recommend?

Please state license type / cost, supported compilers (i.e. GCC and or VC++) for the library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

LGPL. Standard download from official website is designed for GCC. VC++ port is available from [here](http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/computing/gmp4win.php).

Comment: I can't in all honesty recommend GMP for serious work since it has the nasty habit of exiting violently on out-of-memory problems. This is, in my opinion, unforgivable in what's supposed to be a general purpose library. Don't get me wrong, it's still good and blindingly fast, but only for personal or non-production stuff where you can put up with crashes.

Answer (score 4):

I have not used it, so I'm pointing you here blind:

LibTomMath by Tom St Denis: http://libtom.org/

Public Domain license.  Website mentions that the library builds out of the box with GCC 2.95 [and up] as well as Visual C++ v6.00 [with SP5] without configuration.

A companion book is available: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1597491128](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597491128)

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSL [BN](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html) type.  BSD-style license, pretty sure it's available for windows.

Answer (score 1):

[Best bignum library to solve Project Euler problems in C++ ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047203/best-bignum-library-to-solve-project-euler-problems-in-c)