# Algorithm for binary arithmetic in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, string, binary, math

On paper, binary arithmetic is simple, but as a beginning programmer, I'm finding it a little difficult to come up with algorithms for the addition, subtraction, multiplication and division of binary numbers.

I have two binary numbers stored as strings, assume that any leading zeroes have been dropped. How would I go about performing these operations on the two numbers?

Edit: I need to avoid converting them to an int or long.

Comment: Do you want to learn on how to implement the actual algorithm or just do arithmetic operations with these strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation

Comment: Daff, I would like to learn how to implement the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code implements binary addition without actually doing any arithmetic, binary or otherwise. The actual "addition" is done by `lookupTable`, and everything else is straight-up string manipulation. I wrote it with the intention of making it as instructive as possible, emphasizing the process instead of efficiency. Hope it helps.

```
public class BinaryArithmetic {
    static String[] lookupTable = {
        "0+0+0=00",
        "0+0+1=01",
        "0+1+0=01", 
        "0+1+1=10",
        "1+0+0=01",
        "1+0+1=10",
        "1+1+0=10",
        "1+1+1=11",
    };
    static String lookup(char b1, char b2, char c) {
        String formula = String.format("%c+%c+%c=", b1, b2, c);
        for (String s : lookupTable) {
            if (s.startsWith(formula)) {
                return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 1);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    static String zeroPad(String s, int length) {
        while (s.length() < length) {
            s = "0" + s;
        }
        return s;
    }   
    static String add(String s1, String s2) {
        int length = Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length());
        s1 = zeroPad(s1, length);
        s2 = zeroPad(s2, length);
        String result = "";
        char carry = '0';
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            String columnResult = lookup(s1.charAt(i), s2.charAt(i), carry);
            result = columnResult.charAt(1) + result;
            carry = columnResult.charAt(0);
        }
        if (carry == '1') {
            result = carry + result;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(add("11101", "1001"));
    }
}
```

---

While we're at it, I might as well do `multiply` too.

```
static String multiply(String s1, String s2) {
    String result = "";
    String zeroSuffix = "";
    for (int i = s2.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (s2.charAt(i) == '1') {
            result = add(result, s1 + zeroSuffix);
        }
        zeroSuffix += "0";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Binary string to int:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("10101011", 2);
int j = Integer.parseInt("00010", 2);
```

Then you can do anything you please with the two ints, eg:

```
i = i + j;
i = i - j;
```

And to get them back to a binary string:

```
String s = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have noted that I need to avoid converting them to an int or long.

Answer (score 5):

The algorithms, from wikipedia:

**Addition:**

> The simplest arithmetic operation in
>   binary is addition. Adding two
>   single-digit binary numbers is
>   relatively simple, using a form of
>   carrying:
>
> ```
> 0 + 0 → 0
> 0 + 1 → 1
> 1 + 0 → 1
> 1 + 1 → 0, carry 1 (since 1 + 1 = 0 + 1 × 10 in binary)
> ```
>
> Adding two "1" digits produces a digit
>   "0", while 1 will have to be added to
>   the next column.

**Subtraction**:

> Subtraction works in much the same
>   way:
>
> ```
> 0 − 0 → 0
> 0 − 1 → 1, borrow 1
> 1 − 0 → 1
> 1 − 1 → 0
> ```
>
> Subtracting a "1" digit from a "0"
>   digit produces the digit "1", while 1
>   will have to be subtracted from the
>   next column. This is known as
>   borrowing. The principle is the same
>   as for carrying. When the result of a
>   subtraction is less than 0, the least
>   possible value of a digit, the
>   procedure is to "borrow" the deficit
>   divided by the radix (that is, 10/10)
>   from the left, subtracting it from the
>   next positional value.

**Multiplication**:

> Multiplication in binary is similar to
>   its decimal counterpart. Two numbers A
>   and B can be multiplied by partial
>   products: for each digit in B, the
>   product of that digit in A is
>   calculated and written on a new line,
>   shifted leftward so that its rightmost
>   digit lines up with the digit in B
>   that was used. The sum of all these
>   partial products gives the final
>   result.
>
> Since there are only two digits in
>   binary, there are only two possible
>   outcomes of each partial
>   multiplication:
>
> ```
> * If the digit in B is 0, the partial product is also 0
> * If the digit in B is 1, the partial product is equal to A
> ```
>
> For example, the binary numbers 1011
>   and 1010 are multiplied as follows:

```
            1 0 1 1   (A)
          × 1 0 1 0   (B)
          ---------
            0 0 0 0   ← Corresponds to a zero in B
    +     1 0 1 1     ← Corresponds to a one in B
    +   0 0 0 0
    + 1 0 1 1      
    --------------- 
    = 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Working with binary arithmetic is really no different than the more familiar base 10. Let's take addition for example

```
                 (1)     (1)
182      182      182      182      182
845      845      845      845      845
--- +    --- +    --- +    --- +    --- +
           7       27      027     1027
```

So what did you do? You right-align the numbers to add, and you proceed right-to-left, adding one digit at a time, carrying over +1 to the left as necessary.

In binary, the process is exactly the same. In fact, it's even simpler because you only have 2 "digits" now, 0 and 1!

```
             (1)                           (1)       (1)
11101      11101      11101      11101      11101      11101      11101
 1001       1001       1001       1001       1001       1001       1001 
----- +    ----- +    ----- +    ----- +    ----- +    ----- +    ----- +
               0         10        110       0110      00110     100110
```

The rest of the operations work similarly too: the same process that you use for base 10, works for base 2. And again, it's actually simpler because there are only 2 "digits", 0 and 1. This simplicity is why hardware likes the binary system.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the binary strings to Integers and then operate on the Integers, e.g.

```
String add(String s1, String s2) {
    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
    int i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
    return Integer.toBinaryString(i1 + i2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [BitSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class is very straight-forward to use for bit-level operations.