# how can i split a string containing a 32bit number into two 16bit register

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation

I am working on a project to calculate gcd of two 32bit number in 16bit arithmetic assembly. So, how can I split a string containing a 32bit number into two 16bit register?

For example:
"1234567891" -> dx=**0100 1001 1001 0110** & ax=**0000 0010 1101 0011**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to look at using something called arbitrary precision. Its quite a common process for making calculations on numbers that are larger than a processor may be able to handle.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation) previous stackoverflow question as it has a good answer to explain how this may be achieved.

Be aware that if you multiply two 32 bit numbers then you may need a 64 bit number to store the result!

Comment: yes you are trust , i know that you said.i lookup many site as wikipedia , stack_over_flow etc.but i didnt find my expected answer .in other words there is no answer or source code about it :D

Comment: recently i done a project in c++, like this-handle unlimited digits-but in assembly i cant do this.in other words i know what to do, but at first only i dont know how convert sequence of ascii character-at most contained 10digit- to a number and more important split it into two 16bit register like ax:dx.if its possible there are no problem to do other section of my project.i write a 16bit version of gcd finder that it works properly as shown :

Comment: `
.model flat
.stack 1024
.data
x dw 2620
y dw 3600
.code
.startup
push x
push y
call gcd 
.exit
gcd proc near
push bp
mov bp,sp
mov bx,[bp+4]
mov cx,[bp+6]
cmp bx,0
je retern
mov ax,cx
xor dx,dx
div bx
push bx
push dx
call gcd
retern:
mov dx,cx
pop bp
ret 2
gcd endp
end
`