# Adding numbers having more digits after decimal point

Tags: vb.net, numbers, double, decimal-point

How to add two decimal numbers, having more than 18 digits, (ex: "0.12345678901234567345342343" and "-0.540811569342790340234") to all the decimal places accurately in vb.net. I tried using double datatype but it did round-off for 18 digits after decimal point. So how i can achieve this?

Comment: Very nice explanation in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation). Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Decimal` data type instead. It gives you precision of [28-29 significant digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - should be enough for most needs.