# How can I insert a larger number string for long long?

Tags: c++

I'm just starting out, I think I've been using c++ for an hour. How can I insert a string of longer numbers using the long long data type? Every time I get to command prompt and insert a string of long numbers, I get the error message I set (invalid value)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long x, y;
    cout << "Insert the first number: ";
    if (cin >> x) {
        cout << "Insert the second number: ";
        cin >> y;
        cout << "The result is: " << x + y;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid value!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to attempt to make the computer calculate the sum of any given string of random numbers (e.g., 125123412341235123412351235123412341235)

Comment: What is your exact input?

Comment: Why do you need a number bigger than a `long long` can accommodate? There's an air of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) about this question.

Comment: Works for me using the limits of a long long as input. https://godbolt.org/z/GKvroMrhh

Comment: I want to attempt to make the computer calculate the sum of any given string of random numbers (e.g., 125123412341235123412351235123412341235)

Comment: Consider the classic credit card "number" issue, where the solution is realizing that credit card numbers are strings of digits rather than integers.

Comment: I'm guessing you're really asking how to read a number that is not representable by this datatype. The input will fail if the value being read exceeds the allowed range. In that case, you should read the number as a string and then manually add it. Or use a big integer library. Not really the kind of task for "1 hour total experience in C++".

Comment: Here's an old answer of mine that provides a very basic function for adding two (positive) numeric strings represented in base 10: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15375420

Comment: You don't need your input as an integer. You just need a string. Iterate over it character by character, convert the digits to (very small) integers, and add them to a sum.

Comment: All numeric types in a computer have a maximum. Integers can precisely represent whole numbers, but they run out of "space" relatively quickly. Floating point numbers can support huge numbers, but run out of precision fairly quickly. You need a Big Integer structure, something that does not come stock in C++.

Comment: Should work as long as your `sizeof(long long)` is 16 or larger.

Comment: *I'm just starting out, I think I've been using c++ for an hour* -- Then I suggest you learn C++ first before partaking in online coding puzzles.  Adding two strings of digits in the way done by grade-school math students, where you process each column of digits from right to left is relatively simple (not actually a beginner problem), but still you need an understanding of C++ first to do this.

Comment: I've solved the issue, thank you for your help. However, regarding @Sam Varshavchik I honestly don't understand what you meant. I simply read some things on cplusplus and wanted to see if I can do something on my own without receiving help... Have a good day, I guess...

Comment: @Eljay I know you're just trying to make a point, but have you ever seen a system where `long long` is that large?  I know I haven't.

Comment: @Grizzy -- *I've solved the issue* -- Unless you took the code straight from paddy's solution, I have a hard time believing that a beginner in C++ could have solved this problem in such a short time.

Comment: @MarkRansom • I worked on a Linux port where `int` was 64-bit, `long` was 128-bit, and `long long` was 256-bit.  So... yes.  (The project folded. The managers determined that there wasn't a need/market for this.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I looked over what paddy sent me and added some things from there, and the code worked without any problems. So yeah, I did that, lmao.

Comment: A fun exercise would be to modify that code to support negatives.

Comment: @paddy this is a task for tomorrow and I will post the code here.

Comment: @Grizzy Or to do subtraction.  Then multiplication.  Then the even tougher one -- division.

Comment: @grizzy Can't wait to see it. Ping me when you do.

Comment: @Grizzy , one of the common occurrences on Stack Overflow is folks learning a language running off to online programming competition sites to practice before they're done learning, getting in way over their heads, and running to Stack Overflow for a quick solution. They come away learning nothing because they don't know enough to understand the answers yet. Sam's not assuming the worst, he's assuming the disappointingly typical. The takeaway for you should be something like "Don't waste your time learning form online challenges. Learn and *then* complete for fun (if that's your thing)."

Comment: @user4581301
How can you learn without putting it into practice or at least trying to think through what you're doing? This is what I try to do, to document and put into practice as much as possible to understand what I'm doing. It's pointless to learn a lot and not know how to do anything... by "nothing" I mean practical, to have the ability to "think." Thanks tho for your comment.

Comment: Here's how you learn: you [get a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/), open chapter 1 and start reading. The textbook will include, as part of its organized, structured, study course, plenty of "practice" on your own, but in a logical order, arranged from introductory concepts to advanced. Nobody will learn C++ by watching Youtube videos, reading blogs, or web sites, or doing random coding puzzles. One doesn't learn physics by trying to "practice" building airplanes. One does not learn C++ by trying "practice" C++ coding.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Okay, I bet you don't seem to realize that you can find the information from that book, online. Secondly, I didn't mention YouTube, but yes, it's an option to understand a concept like programming. Regarding your arguments about practice, you need to develop your power or instinct or however you want to call it to "think"when doing something, to be able to solve the problem. What I'm trying to do is develop my ability to "think", and if you feel overwhelmed by the question or bothered, why did you waste your time reading it to give me an answer? Let's move on...

Comment: Practice is key to the whole thing, and punching up in an attempt to learn more is admirable, but only up to a point. After that, it's silly. Like trying to learn to box by entering in professional matches. You'll spend too much time unconscious on the mat to have picked up any of the finer parts of the art. No, instead you take it slow enough that you can understand the concepts flying at you, sort them, store them, and understand how to apply them. That speed will change based on the person and on the concepts you're learning.

Comment: A side note on cplusplus.com: The main goal at cplusplus.com is to ease the entry into what can be a very complicated topic, and sometimes you'll find that in simplifying, [they wind up being wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children). It's a good place to start but when it doesn't work, take a look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). It often reads like it was written by Martian lawyers, but a program is basically a legal agreement between you and the computer, bound by some really anally-retentive rules.

Comment: I second Sam's low opinion of YouTube. Too many content farmers who don't give a crap if you learned anything valuable so long as you watched and maximized the ad revenue. The Internet in general is dangerous to use until you know enough of the language to tell a bullshit artist or [Dunning-Kruger Award Winner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) from a domain expert dishing out good advice.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You don't get my point, but.... thank you i guess

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for your support, appreciate it.

Comment: @Grizzy -- The only YT videos that are worthwhile are the ones that focus on semi-advanced to advanced topics concerning C++ and its usages, for example the videos from CppCon or other conference-related videos.  Almost all of the "beginner C++" YT videos are garbage.

Comment: @user4581301 one of the worst qualities of the programming challenges is that you're practicing things that will NEVER be useful to you in real life.  This question is a perfect example, how often have you needed to work with unlimited size integers?  The built-in limits are quite practical to work within.

Comment: @mark Ransom I bet you were a very good student and you only studied what was necessary, without being creative or trying to see what happens (curiosity).

Comment: Not at all true.  In 10th grade I tried to calculate pi to 500 decimal places using Basic which only had about 6 digits of precision.  Didn't make it, but I think I got as far as 200 places.  The point is that I was doing it as a challenge that was personally meaningful, not from some random test (online didn't exist at the time).

Comment: This comment thread is digressing into conversation and should probably be taken elsewhere.

Comment: I recommend not doing that just yet. You are objectively not ready to tackle this problem. But if you really really want, you can start by searching for the term *bignum* in the search engine of your choice. Spend a day reading what you can, then hopefully you will be able to ask more meaningful questions. Not to solve the problem, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple: do not treat the *number* as an *integer*. Read it in as a string, and iterating over the characters in that string, convert the digits to very small numbers, and sum them.

```
int main() {
    std::string input = "125123412341235123412351235123412341235";

    long long sum = 0;

    for (char ch : input) {
        sum += ch - '0';
    }

    std::cout << sum << "\n";
}
```

Should you actually want to sum multiple such numbers together, you need to simulate grade school addition adding digits with carries. An example follows, though for the moment we'll pretend negative numbers don't exist.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string add(std::string a, std::string b) {
    // Code that pads both strings representing 
    // numbers to the same length, padded with '0'
    auto max = std::max(a.length(), b.length());

    std::ostringstream temp;

    temp
      << std::setw(max)
      << std::setfill('0')
      << std::right
      << a;

    a = temp.str();

    temp.str("");
    temp << b;

    b = temp.str();

    // A string stream we can add "added" digits to.
    std::ostringstream result_ss;

    int carry = 0;

    for (std::size_t i = max; i > 0; i--) {
        // Convert characters to numeric digit equivalents.
        int d1 = a[i-1] - '0';
        int d2 = b[i-1] - '0';
        int sum = d1 + d2 + carry;

        // Insert the result into the string stream,
        // and set the carry appropriately.
        result_ss << (sum % 10);
        carry = sum / 10;
    }

    // The stringstream has been built up "in reverse"
    // so we get its string, reverse it, and return it. 
    std::string result = result_ss.str();
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << add("345", "12345") << std::endl;

    // Really big "numbers"
    std::cout 
      << add("1234512345678912345671343545567757755",
             "5672345121111111111111111111111891111")
      << std::endl;
}
```

Result:

```
12690
6906857466790023456782454656679648866
```