# Multiply and add big numbers in java

Tags: java, algorithm, multiplication

I am currently working on a java class that should be able to multiply and add integers so large than no primitive data type can store. I need help coming up with an algorithm to multiply the large numbers together. The method that needs work is `public BigNum mult(BigNum other)`. Any help will be appreciated

```
public class BigNum {

    // F i e l d s

    private String num;  // Representation of our number

    // C o n s t r u c t o r s

    public BigNum(String num) {
        for (int i=0; i<num.length(); i++) {
            if ( ! Character.isDigit(num.charAt(i)) ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
        if ( num.length() == 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.num = num;
    }

    /** Constructs a <tt>BigNum</tt> from a non-negative integer.
     *  @param num The non-negative integer to be interpreted.
     *  @throws IllegalArgumentException if num is negative
     */
    public BigNum(int num) {
        // If num<0, redirected constructor will throw exception due to "-"
        this(""+num);
        for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
           if(num<0)
           {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException();
           }
        }
    }

    /** Constructs a <tt>BigNum</tt> with value zero.
     */
    public BigNum() {
        num="0";
    }

    // P u b l i c   M e t h o d s

    /** Adds two <tt>BigNum</tt> objects' values together and returns a new
      * <tt>BigNum</tt> object with the resulting value.
      *
      * @param other this and other objects get added together
      * @return a new BigNum with the resulting value
      */
    public BigNum add(BigNum other) {
        // Make shorter refer to the shorter num, longer to the longer num
        String shorter = other.num;
        String longer = this.num;
        if (this.num.length() < other.num.length()) {
            shorter = this.num;
            longer = other.num;
        }
        // Prepend zeros to make shorter as long as longer
        while (shorter.length() < longer.length()) {
            shorter = "0" + shorter;
        }
        // Add columns like we did in grade school
        int carry = 0;
        String result = "";
        for (int i=shorter.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            int temp = Character.getNumericValue(shorter.charAt(i)) +
                       Character.getNumericValue(longer.charAt(i)) + carry;
            result = (temp%10)+result;
            carry = temp/10;
        }
        // Handle carry-out, if there is one. Return result
        if (carry == 1) {
            result = "1"+result;
        }
        return new BigNum(result);
    }

    ***public BigNum mult(BigNum other)***
    {
      String shorter = other.num;
      String longer = this.num;
      if(this.num.length()<other.num.length())
      {
         shorter = this.num;
         longer = other.num;
      }
      if(shorter=="0"||longer=="0")
      {
         return new BigNum(0);
      }

      int carry = 0;
      int temp =0;
      String result = "";
      for(int i=shorter.length()-1; i>=0; i--)
      {
         for(int j=longer.lenght()-1; j>=0; j--)
         {
                temp = Character.getNumericValue(shorter.charAt(i)) * 
                       Character.getNumericValue(longer.charAt(j));
         }
      }

      result = temp+result;
      return new BigNum(result);
    }


    /** Returns a string representation of the number. No leading zeros
      * will exist unless the overall value is zero.
      *
      * @return String representation of the BigNum
      */
    public String toString() {
        return num;
    }

    /** Used only for unit testing. When run, should output only trues. */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test constructors
        BigNum test = new BigNum("123");
        System.out.println(test.toString().equals("123"));
        test = new BigNum(123);
        test = new BigNum();
        System.out.println(test.toString().equals("0"));
        // Test addition
        BigNum a = new BigNum();
        BigNum b = new BigNum();
        BigNum c = a.add(b);
        BigNum d = new BigNum();
        BigNum e = new BigNum();
        System.out.println(c.toString().equals("0"));
        a = new BigNum("999");
        b = new BigNum("101");
        c = a.add(b);
        System.out.println(c.toString().equals("1100"));
        a = new BigNum("237468273643278");
        b = new BigNum("87326487236437826");
        c = a.add(b);
        d= new BigNum("1");
        e = a.mult(b);
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println(c.toString().equals("87563955510081104"));
        //String s = "1234";
        //int x =Integer.valueOf(s);
        //System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this a class assignment or do you want to learn how to implement this? Otherwise there is `BigInteger` (and `BigDecimal`) available in the JDK.

Comment: You will need to recall elementary school long multiplication step-by-step.

Comment: This is an assignment and I cannot use BigInteger and BigDecimals that are readily available.

Comment: If you insist on not using `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` from the Java SDK, at least consider the their sources to see how Java efficiently implements them. Some of these things go beyond the logical methods we may use in our heads and instead rely on number theory to optimize for speed on a machine. Wait until you get to operations like taking n-th root, gotta consult good ol' Newton for that.

Comment: Very good post about this over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation?lq=1

Comment: You could simulate a multiplication by doing multiple additions.

Comment: @CPUTerminator I suspect the simple unoptimized ways are good enough for a programming assignment (not a mathematics assignment).

Comment: @immibis I guess... Though some things like squaring and square rooting are not immediately obvious. Imagine trying to square by repeated multiplication (which would be inefficient as well), who knows how long that'll take...

Comment: I can't figure out an algorithm that will multiply the appropriate numbers and implement the carry.

Comment: @CPUTerminator squaring doesn't require repeated multiplication.

Comment: @immibis Never said it did. It was an example of a "obvious" way forward causing unacceptable performance standards.

Comment: @CPUTerminator in fact I can't think of how you *would* use repeated multiplication to square a number.

Comment: @immibis E.g. x^2 = x*x | x^3 = x**x**x | x^5 = xxxxx and so forth... I guess I meant n-th power by repeated multiplication, that I apologize for. x*x done inefficiently on large numbers is still a gaint pain though.

Comment: Is it a requirement to store the number as a `String` internally? It'd be a lot better for your operations if you could store it as a `int[]` or `List<Integer>`

Comment: the numbers that are being multiplied together are so large that primitive types like int or double will not be able to support them, therefore they must be declared as strings

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend storing your big numbers internally as a `int[]` or `List<Integer>` where each item is `< 10` and least significant first. That will make your calculations much easier.

I would also recommend making your `BigNum` immutable (if the assignment allows). That makes it much clearer what you are doing.

You can split your big number multiplication down into separate methods that can be combined using high school maths: `multiplyBy(int)` (digit < 10 - uses simple carries), `multipleByTen` (shift left adding zero), `getDigits` (get list of digit starting with units).

These can then be combined into your standard arithmetic algorithm for long multiplication:

```
BigNum multiplyBy(BigNum bigNum) {
    BigNum answer = BigNum(0);
    for (int digit: getDigits()) {
        answer = answer.add(bigNum.multiplyBy(digit));
        bigNum = bigNum.multiplyByTen();
    }
    return answer;
}
```