# Store a long decimal in C

Tags: c, variables

I am trying to do a physics problem and need to store a value around 5 * 10<sup>-11</sup>;
After trying float, long double and a few others none of them see to be long enough. Is there a data type that will allow me to do so?
Thanks

```
long double I = 0;
I = 0.01902*pow(0.00318,3)/12;
printf("%Lf\n",I);
```

Output is 0.000000

Comment: Take a look at *arbitrary precision numbers*, e.g. in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation) or [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: What exactly makes you conclude that `float` or `long double` are not "long enough"?

Comment: IIRC, that value should be encoded correctly in an IEEE754 single-precision floating point number.

Comment: Show us your code. You're probably screwing up your output formatting or something so the result just looks like it's zero.

Comment: Try `printf("%e\n", 5e-11)`. It seems to work, no?

Comment: @Jonski: According to your edit, your problem is due to the precision you're printing the number in. Read about `printf()` format specifiers.

Comment: @KemyLand Thanks man, just needed to put this as my print statement printf("%.15Lf\n",I);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value

Comment: What compiler are you using? Some of the Windows compilers mess up `long double`

Comment: Note that you are performing the calculation in `double` precision and then assigning the result to `long double`.  To do the calculation in `long double` precision, put the `L` suffix on your constants, and call `powl` instead of `pow`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
long double I = 0;
I = 0.01902*pow(0.00318,3)/12;
```

At this moment, `I`'s value is approximately `5.096953e-11`. Then...

```
printf("%Lf\n", I);
```

The sole format specifier in this `printf()` call is `%Lf`. This indicates that the argument is a `long double` (`L`), and that it should be printed as a floating-point number (`f`). Finally, as the precision (number of digits printed after the period) is not explicitly given, it is assumed to be `6`. This means that up to 6 digits will be printed after the period.

There are several ways to fix this. Two of them would be...

```
printf(".15Lf\n", I);
```

This will set the precision to be `15`. As such, 15 digits will be printed after the period. And...

```
printf("%Le\n", I);
```

This will print the number in scientific notation, that is, `5.096953e-11`.  It too can be configured to print more digits if you want them.