# atof() returns inaccurate value

Tags: c, atof

I am trying to convert a string with max.10 characters into a float-value, using the `atof`-function. Unfortunately it is not working as the function returns an inaccurate value.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 10
#define BUFFER (MAX_LENGTH + 1)

int validateInput(char input[]);

int main(void)
{
        int return_value;
        char tocheck1[] = "1234567.89";
        return_value = validateInput(tocheck1);
        if (return_value == 0) {
                printf("\nInvalid.");
        } else {
                printf("Valid.");
        }
        return 0;
}


int validateInput(char input[])
{
        float floatvalue;
        char validationstring[BUFFER];
        int result;
        if (strlen(input)>MAX_LENGTH) {
                return 0;
        }
        floatvalue = atof(input);
        printf("\n%f", floatvalue);
        sprintf(validationstring, "%.2f", floatvalue);
        printf("\n%s", validationstring);
        result = strcmp(input, validationstring);
        if (result == 0) {
                return 1;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}
```

For testing-purposes I am printing the `float`-value and the `validationstring` and I have identified that the converted string differs from the input-string.

I also tried to use `double` instead of `float` but it is still inaccurate.

The terminal-output is as follows:

```
1234567.875000
1234567.88
Invalid.
```

Why are the digits of the `input`-string converted wrong? I understand why `sprintf` returns the ".88" decimals and thus I understand the "Invalid"-Output. But I don`t understand why in the first step it is not converting correctly.

It is an university-task where I should do it as described and they want me to do a conversion of an input (max. 10 digits), convert it with `atof` to `float`-value, convert it back with `sprintf` and then finally compare it with the initial string (input).

Happy to hear from you, guys. If you need further info, please let me know.

Comment: This is nature of the [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) If you need an accurate values, you'll need much more memory and CPU, i.e. Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168077/floating-point-inaccuracies-in-c

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: 32-bit float is only accurate to 7 decimal digits. A 64-bit double is accurate to 16 decimal digits.

Comment: @Dipstick: [No, they are not.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614323/298225)

Comment: Shouldn't `printf("Invalid.");` be `printf("\nValid.");`? (But you should really print the newlines at the end of the lines, not at the start of the lines.)

Comment: "It is an university-task where I should do it as described and they want me to do a conversion of an input (max. 10 digits), convert it with atof to float-value, convert it back with sprintf and then finally compare it with the initial string (input)." Unless you omit significant information from your assignment, it cannot possibly work. A 10-character string converted to a `float` and back will not be equal to the original input except in a relatively few special cases.

Comment: @Ian Abbott: It should return "Invalid" when the value is "0" as "0" represents that the initial string is >10 characters or the converted new string is not the same as the initial string. Thanks for the tip with newline ...

Comment: @ess-te Yes, but currently, the code prints `"\nInvalid."` when the test fails, and `"Invalid."` when the test passes. The only difference is that one of them prints a newline and the other doesn't.

Comment: @IanAbbott: You`re right. I`ve posted old code, but also with correction it goes wrong :-)
Edited now

Comment: If I change `float floatvalue;` to `double floatvalue;`, it prints out `1234567.890000` `1234567.89Valid`, which seems correct. The double value returned by `atof()` is actually 1234567.88999999989755451679229736328125 exactly. `printf` `%f` correctly rounds that to 6 decimal places as 1234567.890000, and `sprintf` `%.2f` correctly rounds it to 2 decimal places as 1234567.89.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: Re “it cannot possibly work”: It works fine. The program converts the input to `float` using `atof`, converts it back with `sprintf`, and compares it to the initial string. That is what is supposed to do. The program prints “Invalid”, which is the correct result.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Re “Yes, but currently, the code prints "\nInvalid." when the test fails”: FYI, this is not a good way to think about tests. The purpose of a test is to **find** a problem, not to prove there are none. When a test reports a problem is found, it has performed successfully, and that is a positive result. People may be most familiar with this from medical tests, which report positive for problems found, and it applies to engineering too. It is important because the mentality should be to try to find bugs, not to try not to find them. Human psychology makes the former work better.

Comment: @ess-te: Re “It is an university-task where I should do it as described and they want me to do a conversion of an input (max. 10 digits), convert it with atof to float-value, convert it back with sprintf and then finally compare it with the initial string (input)”: Your program does that, and it correctly prints “Invalid”. Why do you think that is not the result you were supposed to get from this assignment? Was it an assignment to show you the limits of numerical computing?

Comment: @EricPostpischil *"Invalid”, which is the correct result* It depends on what is considered correct by the test grader. We are not being told that.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: What the described code should produce is not a matter of opinion. In C implementations that use the common format for `float`, `sprintf(…, "%.2f", atof(1234567.89))` produces a string that differs from “1234567.89”, and that is a fact regardless of any consideration by the grader.

Comment: Your `validationString` buffer is not large enough to store 10 digits, a decimal point, and a null terminator. You should make it larger.

Comment: @ess-te Consider  "max.10 characters into a float-value, " is at least 10^10 combinations using digits.  More if we uses `'-'`, `' '`, and `'.'`.  Common `float` is 32-bit to about 4*10^9 combinations.  It should be then evident that not all input combinations lead to a distinctive `float`.  Something has to give.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What the *described* code *produces* is not a matter of opinion. It produces what it produces. What the *desired* code *should* produce is not a a matter of opinion either. It should produce what the assignment says. The two things are not necessarily the same though.

Comment: @IanAbbott True about [buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557041/atof-returns-inaccurate-value#comment136729123_77557041).  With input of "max.10 characters" plus a _null character_, output buffer should at least handle `sprintf(validationstring, "%.2f", 9999999999);` which is 10+1+2+1 or 14.  By why skimp? Make it 50 to handle `-FLT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux Or could use `%.10g` to print 10 digits and switch to exponential output format when out of the normal range. A 17 char buffer will be okay for 10 digit significand and up to 3 exponent digits (although 32-bit float only needs 2 exponent digits).

Comment: @IanAbbott Maybe off by 1? 17 good for 2 digit exponent: "sd.dddddddddesdd\0".  Need 18 for 3 expo digits.

Comment: @chux Yes I was off by 1.

Comment: @chux Strangely, GCC 13's `-Wformat-overflow` also seems to be off by 1.

Comment: @all: Thanks for your input. I now have some feedback from my professor ... and the task was exactly to find out what I found out. So obviously did everything right...

Answer (score 0):

In the format commonly used for `float`, the closest representable value to 1,234,567.89 is 1,234,567.875.

The IEEE-754 binary32 format, also called “single precision,” is commonly used for the `float` type. In this format, numbers are represented as ±*f*•2<sup>*e*</sup>, where *f* is an integer, 0 ≤ *f* < 2<sup>24</sup>, and *e* is an integer, −149 ≤ *e* ≤ 104. (This is expressible using different scalings for *f* so that it is not an integer and the range for *e* is adjusted accordingly so the forms are mathematically equivalent.)

Numbers in this form are encoded using 32 bits:

- The + or − is encoded in one bit.
- Of the 24 binary digits of *f*, 23 are encoded explicitly in 23 bits.
- The exponent range, −149 ≤ *e* ≤ 104, spans 254 numbers, so this is encoded in 8 bits. 8 bits can encode 256 numbers, so the other two values are used to represent infinities, NaNs (“Not a Number”), and cases where the leading bit of *f* is zero.

In this format, the closest representable number to 1,234,567.89 is +9,876,543•2<sup>−3</sup> = 1,234,567.875. Since *f* must be an integer, the next greater representable number is +9876544•2<sup>−3</sup> = 1,234,568. (We cannot make the number any finer by using 2<sup>−4</sup> instead of 2<sup>−3</sup> because then *f* would have to change to about double of 9,876,543, and that would make it larger than 2<sup>24</sup>.)

So, when `atof("1234567.89")` returns 1,234,567.875, it is returning the best possible result.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and hints on the other topics which are, obviously, the solution to my question. 

I still struggle to find the right way to solve my uni-task but maybe I`ll find a workaround...