# use of multi register to work with large numbers

Tags: algorithm, assembly, x86, real-mode

how to use of multi register to work with large numbers?

---

assuming you need to do some calculation of large numbers that can not fit in 32 bit register and the only way to solve your problem is  use registers, the memory solution is not available

---

like multiplication and deviation:

we have `edx:eax`

is there is a way or an algorithm or an instruction to put your value directly in `reg1:reg2:reg3...regn`   ?

like if you have `dq` in memory how to store it in two register of 32 bit  in one shout if it is possible

Comment: i vote up because this is a legacy question  , when i was learning asm in university the professor of computer  architecture always tell us about this old problem so i never ask my self such how they do it in  64k of ram and 16 bit register

Comment: You can put any value directly into reg1, reg2, reg3 ... etc.. with separate instructions. You can also add and subtract them, etc.. The x86 has already one way of concatenating two registers into single larger one, for example `ah:al = ax`, but that practice was abandoned with 80386 providing new 32 bit extended `eax`, which has only lower 16b `ax` accessible separately, and 64b `rax` follows this with further twist of any-write-into-eax-clears-upper-32b. As you can easily build any algorithm from separate instructions, there's no urgent need in CPU to have extra instructions for it.

Comment: i know this kind of wrap around but i still bad idea if you have lard program  or game  .god bless compilers

Comment: @YassineBoato: they do it the same way modern x86 does extended-precision math in 64-bit chunks.  Using `add/adc` for addition, and `mul` (full N x N => 2N multiply).  For example, https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/x86_64/mul_1.asm (AT&T syntax) multiplies an arbitrary-length number by a 64-bit number.  See https://gmplib.org/manual/Low_002dlevel-Functions.html for docs on what the low-level functions do.

Comment: Or more generally: [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation) explains the algorithms in C.

Comment: @alaadine that's no problem to the compilers because [maths on values double the width of the registers is very simple](https://godbolt.org/g/uk19tq). For more complex operations like multiplies and divides there are already support in libraries for that. However most modern systems are 64-bit so there's no much need for bigint support for most applications nowadays, as almost no one needs to use 128-bit integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With old 8080 and Z80 CPUs there was direct support for multi-register operations, although only with pre-selected pairs of registers, like the Z80 had 8 bit registers `a, b, c, d, e, h, l` and instructions like `add hl,de` operating with 16b pairs of them (but for example this 16b `add` does not update flags, contrary to 8 bit `add d,e`, etc. and they are somewhat slower than 8 bit variants, so there's still some penalty for using 16 bit values, although usually 16b pairs are more efficient than same task written with 8 bit instructions only.

This feature of 8080 was inspiration (*I guess, no facts*) of 8086 `ah:al = ax` 8b registers forming 16b registers and having instructions operating not only with 8 bit registers but also with the pre-selected pairs. Although 8086 is lot more like native 16b CPU, so this feature is rather "let support the breakdown of 16b registers to 8b for making migration of 8b SW easier", than "let support pairing two 8b registers for 16b math".

After that with 80386 this practice was abandoned, and the 32 bit extension of `a` register called `eax` didn't add new alias for upper 16b part, making it harder to access it separately (the low 16b is aliased by original `ax`, which is needed for backward compatibility with 8086/186/286 any way).

Because those extra 16b registers of upper parts of `eax, ebx, ...` would bump up the number of registers considerably, making the old instruction encoding not feasible any more, and actually with the nature of x86 instruction set it would be quite difficult to keep basic instructions mostly 2 bytes long, the extra combinations would probably raise that average toward 3 bytes.

Now your idea of supporting many more multi-register combinations would explode the required opcodes even more and faster, so such ISA would need probably about 4-6 bytes per instruction on average.

While basically it took quite some decade before people did start to feel seriously limited by 16b math (having values from 0 to 65535 did look to me as quite a lot, back when I was doing some programs on ZX Spectrum with Z80 CPU), and the 32b was true breakthrough, even most of the real-life human math task like prices in shop/etc. can be done with 32b integers easily. It took another decade+ to hit this limit more often (than just in special cases), like when whole movies did start to be encoded on disk, and disks generally went over gigabytes size.

So what you are asking is usually not needed at all (pushed even much further by the 64b options today, which covers insane range of values), and when one eventually needs that, it's very simple to build that from separate instructions... like for example 80386+ code to add `eax:ebx:ecx` with `esi:edi:edx`:

```
    ; eax:ebx:ecx += esi:edi:edx  (96b integer addition)
    add  ecx, edx
    adc  ebx, edi
    adc  eax, esi
```

Simple enough to not justify the above mentioned explosion of opcode sizes for putting such thing directly into the CPU.