# How to store a number with a 1000 digits in a register

Tags: assembly, arm

I know it is not possible in one register but what is the best method to store it? I am trying to solve Euler's problem 25 in arm assembly. I have the fibonacci part completed but cannot figure out how to keep doing it until I get to a thousand digits. It would be around the 4782th fibonacci number.

Storing in separate registers, but that would require a lot of registers.

Link to eulers problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=25

Answer (score 2):

The number `101000` consists of a little over 3300 bits. Unless ARM has hundreds of 32-bit registers that you can use for this, it's *not* going to be done in registers.

Even if it *did* have that many registers, it's probably still not optimised toward treating them all as a single unit.

What you will probably need to do is to store these things in memory (as a `{sign, numBytes, byteArray[]}` structure of some description). You can look at this [earlier answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation/1218185#1218185) to see one way for implementing basic arithmetic operations on "bignum" types.

Comment: Sorry my wording for my question was a little weird. I know its not possible to store a number that large in a register, but I need help on how I could go about storing it so I could use it in assembly.

Comment: AArch64 has thirty-two 128-bit vector registers, `q0..31` so there actually *is* enough room (4096 bits).  Not on ARM32 though, with only q0..15 or d0..31.  But with no mechanism for carry propagation from one SIMD element to the next, that's not useful. :P

Comment: Anyway, @TerminatorDe: you probably don't want a byte array, but rather an array of words, so you can work in base 2^32.  Or since you care about *decimal* digits, maybe in base 10^9 in a 32-bit word (like Python does), emulating carry with compares.  For more tricks for working with large Fibonacci numbers, see [Extreme Fibonacci](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/133618).  e.g. you can find `F(2n)` from `F(n)` (but then you'd need to implement extended-precision multiply).  Or keeping only the leading several digits of `F(n)` because it grows quickly enough to make the low digits irrelevant.