# division of two 50 digit-numbers in C

Tags: c

Hi this is my code and it does not work
I want to do division of first number and second number (There are large number ==> 50 digits)
it returns 0 when there are those inputs at top

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

//inputs a = "85548187429241610817174857069711212619572772836876"
//inputs b = "43488970802022113439274600911335838550652591258202"

int main() {
    char a[50],b[50];
int r,q=0;
printf("1:");
scanf("%s",&a);
printf("2:");
scanf("%s",&b);

r=atoi(a);

if(atoi(a)<atoi(b)){return 0 ;}

while(r>atoi(b)){
q = q+1;
r = r-atoi(b);

}
printf("%d %d",q,r);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `atoi` is good for maybe 10 digits. Absolutely does not work for 50 digit numbers.

Comment: @MohamadSh And what should the code return?

Comment: Also, division by repeated subtraction is really slow if the first number is much larger than the second number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218149/arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-explanation)

Comment: And then there's the buffer overflow problem. If you use `scanf` to read a string of 50 digits, the array must have at least 51 characters, because `scanf` puts a null byte at the end of the string.

Comment: You obviously can't store the number in integer variables, since their ranges are bounded.  One approach is to store them in integer arrays, with one digit per entry.  Then just do long division, the same way you'd do it by hand.

Comment: Kind of irrelevant considering all the other problems, but you're calling `atoi(b)` _twice_ for _each iteration_ of your loop. It should be called once, before the loop, and stored in a variable.

Comment: Repeated subtraction is a poor algorithm even for `int`: for a 50 digit value you'll need to wait at *Milliways*, the Restaurant at the End of the Universe.

Comment: `while(r>atoi(b))` You want `>=` here.... Then the code might actually work for more appropriate (smaller) values.

Comment: Also: `scanf("%s",&a);` ==> `scanf("%49s",a);` Not only the overrun problem, but the wrong use of "address of"...

Comment: Please don't make drastic edits like that. It invalidates the answer

Comment: @WeatherVane For *this particular problem*, repeated subtraction is fine, because the quotient is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Troubles:

**Not compiling with all warnings enable**

`scanf("%s",&a);` --> `scanf("%s", a);`

**Not saving in a big enough buffer**

To save a *string* with length 50, takes size 51.

**Not using a width limit**

Do not use `scanf("%s",...` without a *width*

**Check input return value.**

**`atoi()` is insufficient for such a large string**

**OP needs to write numeric *string* compare, subtract, add functions**

```
int main() {
  char a[50+1],b[50+1];
  printf("1:");
  if (scanf("%50s", a) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failure to read input a.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  printf("2:");
  if (scanf("%50s", b) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failure to read input b.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // Leave the rest for OP.  GTG
  // I estimate OP is about 10% done.
```