# How to represent a binary number size greater than 64 bit

Tags: c++, binary

I have a binary number which I want to represent in decimal. The number is as follows:

```
Binary = 1000 11100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01101110 10110000 10100101
```

Its equivalent hexadecimal representation is as follows :

```
Hexadecimal = 08 E0 00 00 00 00 6E B0 A5
```

I am working on Windows 7 and tried using calculator in programmer mode with Bin (Binary) and Qword. However, it has a limit of 64 bit.

Questions:

- How do I represent this number in decimal?
- Is there any free tool available to represent this number?
- Is there any way in C++11/C++ to achieve this?

Comment: Try this:: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html. BTW why do you want to convert such a long binary in decimal? What is the purpose?

Comment: This link covers a number of libraries for representing big numbers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047203/best-bignum-library-to-solve-project-euler-problems-in-c

Comment: do you need to perform this conversion only once or you want to implement the algorithm?

Comment: I want to implement an algorithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First determine how large a binary number your platform will support. Let's say it's 64. Divide your binary number into chunks of 64 and do the low-order chunk as normal. Now, the low-order bit of the next chunk represents 2<sup>64</sup>. Convert that chunk like a regular number but multiply it by 2<sup>64</sup>. You could use this technique as many times as you need. The next chunk you would multiply by 2<sup>128</sup>, then the next by 2<sup>192</sup>, etc.

Comment: Could you explain using the binary number i have mentioned above please ?

Comment: Your answer assumes that a big-integer library is used, correct? Or how do you multiply by `2**64`?

Comment: The problem is that using the widest integral type available at the platform to implement big math you do not make the things not simpler. Please think of implementation of multiplication of two 64-bit integers.

Comment: An example (with the binary number above) will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer [this](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming/What-is-the-trick-to-solve-programming-puzzles-involving-numbers-greater-than-2-64).

You can use the BigInteger class if you are going for JAVA,[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Or download this user-defined library for performing calculations over big numbers in C++, [here](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

Comment: An answer consisting of 'just a link' is not encouraged.  You should give some salient information about what the link contains, at least, because links are prone to link rot.

Answer (score 0):

The easier solution may be to work from the other side. Generate the binary representations of all powers of 10: `0x1, 0xA, 0x64, 0x3E8, 0x2710, ...` until the power of 10 is larger than your number. Then, count how many times each power of 10 occurs (up to 9, of course).

So `0x2F` would be `4 * 0xA + 7 * 0xA`, i.e. 47 decimal.