# Calculating a very High Value in C

Tags: c

How can I write a program for calculating 256^ 1075 in C?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214706/c-or-c-bigint-library-on-microsoft-windows

Comment: if you only need 256^1075 decimial presentation here is it http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=256^1075

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would normally use an arbitrary precision library like the [GNU multiple precision library](http://gmplib.org/) but you need to be aware that there are possible problems on out-of-memory conditions.

I've never struck those conditions but I know that out-of-memory conditions will result in immediate termination of your program, something I find unacceptable in a general purpose library but, if you're only doing it for your own purposes, it shouldn't matter.

Keep in mind that 256<sup>1075</sup> is identical to (2<sup>8</sup>)<sup><sup>1075</sup></sup> or 2<sup>8600</sup> or:

```
721045565498050462828429917412556960604513859802538081873122368911788732956439274225864001642461608356091365725323603142252816890626189696736401581541294285566741028376272823062550082359901794039986298615273210328345626639174106858187711940897476396213895651703726796167860201573778668219366631592506467139237002323894945941153960686586039536926241870456707773431653530015773116176434951659795353009608616446115667285058015334257480475355716852592096374283857537724899247971515783412616992513532848273632589782766271040851331142322771071088389134642984473643738402894918154707844431841213583945783472115999530525333230702437131754966569501527395804654100310782093087523454544803680095205341801516766904126220009222254803233164642288805608897794006153421451603745640461874549192070290357437146114880452134900474637206123870352090538836331361066166004436464109033091161352488478000098719880190760681371193735285926294088907830167065532134813127700660013120296469689114264938082654055243005796763472735288017236752393524167112741532230180683009642635285051448352066165988154443620228918244797456605592199738219102495045082871871749924042812549384175311386227917001287973740197921643037845849558150318478336659332771108283160669871266132735610748059899559920099443863366654359963046955454879286685604643947715878648144465182422254030934432611259761729817942775310594441161575096482080795830737357754824834800998303829642983396836712603779043678758682199370784619630670133509417248505984815076991190213057529038561414712293196578500202094308107205919199315320200458292071386081671529131600951998681568233398639959444445065478510490520755160963389572581156101890222014654426875152661583975418301230503338179030264748031565474013489922191542163505080668367247263962655310515879140996875431342720470207568056785833674837383415271437117705484330992559332192343925631412229552962036545540415751706420159717554066377068012543075927564020874743229021090897051464811533394676447682720815011281441416776254492629990245337221263347551732520660350422723450476787964270274004842480592145998773371409318922960548011085396129032280891833226972242152152697180727904068032245717969766455124404475396853520180332977812778205205309786385376490778465176664848989686125190816554372900664823875404669900296636521380983373661664523506680061456082816532587442510746466657123481269475703351673258759845855904933620481298280491486678485735718545306910493608385077316071337984438572796898083908719338999316913684243081318023001596539495236872846587809109071927554011535392907920457657750570940584466174298869849051365376
```

from `echo '256^1075' | bc`.

---

And, since you asked for a C program, here it is. It's pretty specific for purpose in that it only calculates 256<sup>1075</sup> (or 2<sup>8600</sup> which is the same thing) but you could do other powers of two if you wish. If you bump up the `EXPONENT` and get an overflow, just bump up the `DIGITS` as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Allow for 2600 digits (trial and error) and 2^8600 (256^1075).

#define DIGITS 2600
#define EXPONENT 8600
static int digit[DIGITS];

// Function to print. 'started' is used to strip off leading zeros
//  and is passed in as 1 if overflow occurred.

static void printIt (int started) {
    int i;

    if (started) {
        printf ("Overflow: 1");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++) {
        if (started) {
            printf ("%d", digit[i]);
        } else {
            if (digit[i] > 0) {
                started = 1;
                printf ("%d", digit[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

```
// Doubles the number by using primary school addition with carry.

static int doubleIt (void) {
    int i, carry = 0;

    for (i = DIGITS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        digit[i] = digit[i] * 2 + carry;
        if (digit[i] > 9) {
            digit[i] = digit[i] - 10;
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    return carry;
}

// Main program to calculate the value. Starts with 1
//   and then keeps doubling until we're done.

int main (void) {
    int i, rc;

    digit[DIGITS-1] = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < EXPONENT; i++) {
        printf ("Countdown: %d\n", EXPONENT-i-1);
        if ((rc = doubleIt())) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printIt(rc);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Countdown: 8599
Countdown: 8598
Countdown: 8597
Countdown: 8596
:
Countdown: 4
Countdown: 3
Countdown: 2
Countdown: 1
Countdown: 0

72104556549805046282842991741255696060451385980253808187312236891178
87329564392742258640016424616083560913657253236031422528168906261896
96736401581541294285566741028376272823062550082359901794039986298615
27321032834562663917410685818771194089747639621389565170372679616786
02015737786682193666315925064671392370023238949459411539606865860395
:
78091090719275540115353929079204576577505709405844661742988698490513
65376
```

and this takes about quarter of a second on my old clunker laptop (if I take out the Countdown lines).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it would help to use a library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the gmp library. Otherwise, 256¹⁰⁷⁵ is 2⁸⁶⁰⁰ = 1 << 8600.

Answer (score 2):

256^1075 is, in binary,

```
1000000....0000
```

where there are 8600 zeros.

Comment: That's right, but it seems the OP wants the decimal representation :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an external Library which supports huge numbers like that, or you can write your own (not recommended but very fun to).

if you are indeed using `C++` You can use http://gmplib.org/

Or Just switch over to Java and play with Big Integer (but I don't know what limits it has if any).

Comment: Could you please give an example program which uses GMP library for arithmetics?

Answer (score 1):

In Python is simple: `256 ** 1075`, returning a 2588 digits number. In C, you can use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

As an alternative, you can implement the pencil-and-paper algorithm to multiply `256 x 256 x ... x 256`:

```
char [5000] tempresult;
strcpy(tempresult, "1");

for (i=0; i<1075; i++) {
    /* returns tempresult = tempresult * 256 */
    my_pencil_and_paper_mult(tempresult, "256");
}

printf("%s\n", tempresult);
```

Comment: Can we use without GMP library. Is there any way to store in String or in an array somehow we can calculate the value.

Comment: @Debabrata, Yes, you can. use the pencil-and-paper algortithm to multiply 256 x 256 x ... x 256.